# C#6 expression in .net framework 4

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-6.0

I have this C# 6 expression

```
private int ProxyQueueTimeoutMs => ((MultiProxyCrawlConfiguration) _config).ProxyQueueTimeoutMs;
```

Does exists an equivalent for C# before C#6? 
Is it possible to write a similar method in older versions like .net framework 4?

Comment: That ([Expression-bodied function members](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodied-function-members "Expression-bodied function members")) is not tied to any version of the .NET framework. It's just a compiler/Visual Studio Language feature. What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 uses the C#5 compiler. That feature is not available.

Comment: FYI support for .NET 4.0 ends on January 12, 2016. Instead of looking for workarounds, better upgrade to 4.5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax is called [Expression-bodied function members](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodied-function-members). It is equivalent to called `ProxyQueueTimeoutMs` property with a getter that returns after `=>` part like;

```
private int ProxyQueueTimeoutMs
{
   get 
   { 
       return ((MultiProxyCrawlConfiguration) _config).ProxyQueueTimeoutMs;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can I use Expression-bodied function members in an old application that targets .Net framework 4.0?

Comment: Today I found out the hardway after refactoring legacy code. It didnt support .Net Framework 4.0. Dont be tempted by the IDE to refactor even with PolySharp

Answer (score 2):

Before C# 6 you could do that in this way

```
private int ProxyQueueTimeoutMs
{
    get
    {
        return ((MultiProxyCrawlConfiguration) _config).ProxyQueueTimeoutMs;
    }
}
```

You can write C# 6 in any .NET version, because C# is handled by compiler, and not by the .NET Framework version.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` NuGet package in your project which will replace the C# compiler used so you can target C#6.0.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/

This should enable you to use C#6.0 with .NET 4. I already use it for .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

It's a private read-only property, defined using the new C# 6 expression-bodied property syntax.

The equivalent code for earlier versions of C# is

```
private int ProxyQueueTimeoutMs
{
    get
    {
        return ((MultiProxyCrawlConfiguration)_config).ProxyQueueTimeoutMs;
    }
}
```